# Does the C++ standard have any utilities for handling placement new elegantly?

Tags: c++, c++14, placement-new

I wrote this thing to make sure that things 'allocated' with placement new were always destroyed in the correct fashion. But this seems like something someone would write out of ignorance of the standard library. Is there a better way to do this that's part of the C++ standard library?

```
template <typename T, typename... Args>
auto make_placement_unique(T *p, Args... args)
{
    using ::std::unique_ptr;
    using ::std::forward;
    auto deleter = [](T *p) {
        p->T::~T();
    };
    return unique_ptr<T, decltype(deleter)>{
        new (p) T{forward<Args>(args)...},
        deleter
    };
}

template <typename T, typename... Args>
auto make_placement_unique(void *p, Args... args)
{
    using ::std::forward;
    return make_placement_unique(reinterpret_cast<T *>(p), forward<Args>(args)...);
}
```

Comment: Boost may help: https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_64_0/libs/optional/doc/html/boost_optional/tutorial/in_place_factories.html

Comment: Just a side note, but one of the main points of smart pointers is to manage lifetime of objects, thus reduce memory leaks. With your implementation you just introduced a new possibility to create memory leaks. A naive implementation could look like [auto ptr = make_placement_unique(new SomeClass);](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/d095123300bc8527), and as you see in the valgrind output, produce a memory leak...

Comment: That requires to keep the `unique_ptr` alive, which, IMO, is not the regular way to use it. For example classes as vector which may use placement new, won't store/expose that kind of smart pointers but will use internally something like  [`std::destroy_at`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/destroy_at).

Comment: @Jarod42 Indeed it is not :-D

Comment: @user1810087 - I suppose. One could also do `auto ptr = unique_ptr<T>(other_ptr.get());` and introduce a double free. At some point, you have to wonder if the person is reading the function name or just blindly using whatever will work.